# CSVHelper generic ClassMap with System.Reflection

Tags: .net-core, system.reflection, csvhelper, c#-8.0

I'm trying genericly map the properties of my class to the column names of the CSV without the need to write every single line in the ClassMap like

`Map(rm => rm.PUsrCrRequestedObject).Name("#P_USR_CR_RequestedObject");`

because we have very much columns with mostly the same type of mapping.
So i tried the following code:

```
var classMap = csv.Configuration.AutoMap<RequestMonitoring>();

foreach (var property in typeof(RequestMonitoring).GetProperties())
{
    var columnName = property.Name switch
    {
        "PNdsPn"    => "$P_NDS_PN",
        { } x when x.StartsWith("PUsrCr")   => property.Name.Replace("PUsrCr", "#P_USR_CR_"),
        _           => property.Name
    };
    classMap.Map(requestMonitoring => property).Name(columnName);
}
```

I don't get an error but if i debug the ClassMap the code above hasn't got any effect.

So the question is how can i fix the code snippet or if it's not possible maybe how to apply the same name conversion for every property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```cs
classMap.Map(typeof(RequestMonitoring), property).Name(columnName);
```